# Batch: %%a loop variable can't be compared with a static string

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables, cmd

I'm trying to create a script that will automaticly test alot of keys to activate a programm for my workplace. So my problem is that i can not compare a variable with a given string that i hardcoded. It should be very easy but it just can't compare it even if it's the exactly right line it's outputting.

I've tried giving the variable a differant name. Placed ( ) at many different places so the code becomes not so clustered. I've tried coping the variable by echoing it into a txt file and then copy it out of there inside of my code. Still didn't work. I tried to test my IF to see if that's the problem. But it's working fine. I tried to parse my %%a variable to a %_demo% variable. No effect. So i figured that there might be a character inside that string i cannot read in notepad or something like that. But even when i cut all the things i could possibly think of with delims inside the for-loop and only leave a single word it still wouldnt work.
And i tried SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion which changed nothing.

Inside the inp.txt you will see inside the code is only the captured output of a command from inside batch i've commented the output inside here so you can see how it looks like.
It only searches for  which works so that isn't the problem, i've tested it.

```
REM Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host, Version 5.812 
REM Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten. 
REM ---Processing-------------------------- 
REM --------------------------------------- 
REM <Product key installation successful> 
REM --------------------------------------- 
REM ---Exiting----------------------------- 

for /f "delims=<,>" %%a in ('findstr "<Product key installation successful>" %homepath%\Desktop\inp.txt') do (
set _demo=%%a
)
echo !_demo!
if !_demo! NEQ "Product key installation successful" echo Produkt key installation fehlgeschlagen... && echo.
if !_demo! EQU "" echo Etwas lief schief... && echo !_demo! && echo.
if !_demo! EQU "Product key installation successful" (
*activate it*
) else (
*try again*
)
```

So it should just compare !_demo! to my string i thought that would be the easy part and didn't expect to struggle so much on this line of code.

Comment: Please do not include solutions into your question, post an (clear) answer instead, which you can then accept...

Comment: You need to enclose your variable into quotes. `if "!_demo!" NEQ "Product..."`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution... 
I just put the "Product key installation successful" inside its own variable and it worked. case closed